# What are common design patterns in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, design-patterns, ios

In Java community, design pattern is very common term.

In Object C and Cocoa touch world, there are also some design patterns, such as MVC, target-action, delegate, KVO etc.

The purpose question here is to hear more professional experience from guru. After all, some patterns are common used in iOS development. Just like some are very common in J2EE world.

So question maybe how many common patterns in iOS development field ?  Let me put some here

- MVC
- delegate, target-action ( communication between V and C )
- KVC KVO Notification ( comm between M and C )
- Singleton 
  ....
  ....

Comment: This is rather a large question. Luckily someone has written a 456 page book answering it in detail: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/cocoa/9780321591210

Comment: That book is going to make excellent reading material, thank you!

Comment: yes,a very big topic. I just wanna get some typical examples.

Comment: Voting to close. Design patterns are not framework/language related. They are connected to DESIGN and architecture. The same pattern you use in Java, you use in obj-c and C++. There are some exceptions, some patterns are more used in some frameworks etc but it's only a matter of taste.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Cocoa Fundamentals Guide has a section on a some design patterns:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW6

I don't believe you need access to the Apple Dev Center to view that, but I could be wrong.

Comment: the retired document can be found at https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html

Answer (score 0):

An exaustive document for this is available at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html

Comment: the retired document can be found at https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html

Answer (score 0):

the retired document can be found at https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html